# What is the proper way to manage memory of a class variable / method in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

I'm learning Objective - C and coming from a garbage collected world. I am creating a class (static) variable of a dictionary and I am unsure if I am doing it properly for memory management or not. I'm using a convenience method so the object should be auto-released, but I don't really know if I need to release or retain it in my class.

I can't find clear documentation on how class level objects are managed - any advice is appreciated. Thanks.

```
+(NSDictionary*) polygonNames{        
        NSDictionary* polygonNames = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                      @"Triangle", @"3",
                                      @"Square", @"4",
                                      @"Square", @"4",
                                      @"Pentagon", @"5",
                                      @"Hexagon", @"6",
                                      @"Heptagon", @"7",
                                      @"Octagon", @"8",
                                      @"Nonagon", @"9",
                                      @"Decagon", @"10",
                                      @"Hendecagon", @"11",
                                      @"Dodecagon", @"12",
                                      nil];
        return polygonNames;

    }
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with this code other than that it will create the dictionary every time it is invoked.

Comment: Not answering your question, but -- I see you are storing the number of sides of each polygon as a string. If you really want to store a number, wrap it in an NSNumber  i.e [NSNumber numberWithInt:1] etc.

Comment: Thanks for the number advice, when I was still under the impression that the keys of the dictionary in obj c had to be strings, a quick review of the docs and your comment cleared that up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data structure is immutable and isn't going to change, you can use a *static* variable, like so:

```
+ (NSDictionary *) polygonNames
{
    static NSDictionary *polygonNames = nil;
    if (!polygonNames) polygonNames = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:/* objects and keys */];
    return polygonNames;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - this is helpful. What I'm concerned about is the 'life' of this. Considering that it is static across all instances do I need to ever release it or is it sufficient that it is 'released' at the end of the program. I'm assuming it is created the first time any instance of the class is requested?

Thanks again - b

Comment: It will stay around until the app terminates, which is fine — memory leaks are only big problems (per se) if you're not releasing something which is allocated frequently. For singletons (something that exists only once in memory) it's actually fairly common not to release them, and to rely on the system to release the small amount of memory it uses.

To answer your second question, this allocates the value on first request. If you're using threads, you may want to look here: http://alanquatermain.net/post/114613488/lockless-lazily-initialized-static-global-variables

Comment: Thanks muchly, these answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend the site CocoaDev.com. On which you will find the following rule of thumb:

- If you alloc, retain, or copy it, it's your job to release it. Otherwise it isn't.
- If you alloc, retain, or copy it, it's your job to release it. Otherwise it isn't. Yes: read this again!

Search for "rules of thumb". As I'm not allowed to add hyperlinks..

Basically all class methods named `dictionary*`, `array*` and so on will return an auto-released object which you don't have to retain/release.

For further reading I can recommend the "memory management" page.